# Codename skin intellij

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to Codename One and I'm using Intellij as my IDE. 
I want to chane skin in the simulator but it seems that I can't do it.
I select skins->more and installed my skins that I want to check the app with but I can select them after installing them.

Answer (score 0):

Check that they appear in your `.codenameone` directory. Assuming they are there you can click `Add Skin` and pick them manually.

Comment: Thanx. Can u tell me please where I can find this directory?

Comment: It's under your home/user directory if you are using linux/unix/mac you can use terminal and do `cd ~/.codenameone` to find that directory. On Windows it should be under `c:\Users\YourUserName\.codenameone`